# AngularJS select not binding when using value as value syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am trying to create a Select tag using AngularJS. I am using the ngOptions and ngModel for databinding.

Now: If let's say I have a data source like follows:

```js
$scope.doesNotBind = [
        {ID: 12, Title: "12 - Does not bind"},  
        {ID: 14, Title: "14 - Does not bind"},  
    ];

$scope.doesNotBindModel = {ID: 14, Title: "14 - Does not bind"};
```

```html
<select ng-options="value as value.Title for value in doesNotBind" ng-model="doesNotBindModel">
        <option value> </option>
</select>
```

That will never bind. But if I bind the model like this; it works!

```js
$scope.doesNotBindModel = $scope.doesNotBind[1];
```

Am I using the syntax incorrectly or is this expected behaviour?

I have created a POC to demonstrate fully what I am saying.

[JSFiddle POC](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11549/)

Interestingly enough, when there is no as syntax (no object data binding), it works perfectly (in demo as well)

Thanks!

Edit: I guess this is expected since they by reference eh?

Comment: Updated answer based on your recent edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ngModel` compares by reference, not value. So if you use `ng-options="value as value.Title for value in doesNotBind"`, then your `doesNotBindModel` must be:

JavaScript:

```
$scope.doesNotBindModel = $scope.doesNotBind[1];
```

However, if you still want to set your `doesNotBindModel` in JSON notation,  you can add `track by value.ID` to the `ng-options` expression like this:

HTML:

```
<select ng-options="value as value.Title for value in doesNotBind track by value.ID"
        ng-model="doesNotBindModel">
</select>
```

It also works by adding a `track by` expression, but it is not recommended by Angular's documentation for [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

For the reason behind this please refer the following example:

HTML:

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in values track by item.id" ng-model="selected">
  <option value="">---- not selected ----</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.values = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'aLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'bLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
}];

$scope.selected = { name: 'aSubItem' };
```

With the purpose of preserving the selection, the `track by` expression is always applied to the element of the data source (to `item` in this example). To calculate whether an element is selected, we do the following:

1. Apply `track by` to the elements in the array. In the example: `[1, 2]`
2. Apply `track by` to the already selected value in `ngModel`.

In the example: This is not possible, as `track by` refers to `item.id`, but the selected value from `ngModel` is `{name: 'aSubItem'}`. So the `track by` expression is applied to a wrong object, the selected element can't be found. `<select>` is always reset to the "not selected" option.

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hu5T1Vo3qTkrDqe5PHJy

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I was reading the documentation and I have stumbled upon the trackby expression. Why is it not recommened? They say do not combine it with select as, that is all.

Comment: I have gone through with this. 

Sample: 
<select ng-options="value.Title for value in doesNotBind track by value.ID" ng-model="doesNotBindModel"></select>

Comment: @AlbertHerd I have update my answer to show why the angular's doc said 'Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together.'

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have further taken my example and created a POC. I set the ng model to a value that does indeed exist in the data source, but not referencing it . By removing the select as expression and adding a track by, it successfully works.

In reality doc says do not combine select as with track by, which have eliminated.

Example: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5iMA8f3wEKBM2LsBvpwp)

Answer (score 0):

It's not binding because both are two different objects.

When you create object, a separate memory location is allocated to it.

```
var a = {};

var b = {};
```

if you check whether `a === b`, it will return you false. Because both are two different objects.

That's the reason why

```
$scope.doesNotBindModel = {ID: 57, Title: "57 - Does not bind"};
```

does not bind whereas

```
$scope.doesBindModel = $scope.doesBind[3];
```

Because in later case, you are referring to the same object based on its index.

Comment: Yes yes I realize fully that the issue is the one that you written above. I was looking more for a workaround for the issue.

Probably the workaround is to get a reference to the object when binding..that is the only logical solution I guess.

Comment: Workaround for? If you want to preselect a particular option in select box use can use ng-init or must use the array index way to set a particular item.

Comment: You can use ng-init and call a function. There you can check for particular condition and set a particular item as selected in your ng-model

Comment: Fair enough. For my issue I can set it when I have fetched the data through. So cheers.