# HTML not binding in select

Tags: angular6

In component.ts :

```
optionhtml:any='';
this.optionhtml='<option value="1">Option1</option>';
this.optionhtml+='<option value="2">Option2</option>';
this.optionhtml+='<option value="3">Option3</option>';
```

In component.html :

```
<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2 choose-category" [(ngModel)]="category"  id="inlineFormCustomSelect" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="filterbycategory(category)" [innerHTML]="optionhtml" >
<select>
```

options not binding in Select box using innerHTML

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913317/angularjs-select-not-binding-when-using-value-as-value-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Why pass string from typescript? Instead create collection or array object and bind that to html